Route POST:/export-excel not found in Fastify application
I'm working on a Fastify application where I have set up various routes, including one to export data to an Excel file. However, when I try to access the /export-excel route via a POST request, I'm receiving a 404 error with the message: "Route POST:/export-excel not found."
Here's the relevant part of my setup:
Main Fastify server file:
import { fastify } from 'fastify';
 import cors from '@fastify/cors';
 import fastifyStatic from '@fastify/static';
 import path from 'path';
 import fastifyJwt from '@fastify/jwt';
 import fastifyCookie from '@fastify/cookie';
 import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

 dotenv.config();

 // Import routes
 import { exportExcelRoute } from './routes/create-export-excel';

 const app = fastify();

app.register(fastifyJwt, {
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'default-secret-key',
  cookie: {
    cookieName: 'refreshToken',
    signed: false,
  },
  sign: {
    expiresIn: '7d',
  },
});
app.register(fastifyCookie);
app.register(cors);

// Configure fastify-static to serve files from the "public" folder
app.register(fastifyStatic, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'images'),
  prefix: '/public/', 
});

// Register routes
app.register(exportExcelRoute);

// Start server
app.listen({
  host: process.env.HOST_IP_ADDRESS ?? '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3333,
}).then(() => {
  console.log('HTTP Server Running!');
}).catch((error) => console.log('Error during Data Source initialization:', error));
`

Route definition (create-export-excel.ts):
`import { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify';
import path from 'path';
import ExcelJS from 'exceljs';

export async function exportExcelRoute(app: FastifyInstance) {
  app.post('/export-excel', async (request, reply) => {
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    const sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Land Infos');

    // Add data to the worksheet...

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'landInfos.xlsx');
    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filePath);

    return reply.sendFile('landInfos.xlsx');
  });
}

I receive on Request:
  "message": "Route POST:/export-excel not found",
  "error": "Not Found",
  "statusCode": 404
}```

